# Data Structure, Recursive functions

Tags: function, recursion, data-structures, recurrence

I have tried several times to find the answer of this question and every time my result is 30  but the answer key shows the result to 32 and I don't understand why it should be 32??!! it is a data structure question related to recursive functions;

Let function F be defined recursively as follows:
F(0) = 3; F(n + 1) = 2F(n) + n^2 Then F(3) is given by?

Comment: Please edit the question to show your work for evaluating F(3).  Also, welcome to SO and please read [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a data structures question. If we implement the function in, say, Python:

```
def f(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 3
    else:
        return 2 * f(n-1) + (n-1)**2
```

We get this:

```
f(3)
=> 30
```

So it seems to me that the answer key is mistaken.